# onDestroy() gets called when the back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

In my Activity, I have overrode `onDestory()` and just put a log call to show if this method is being called. (tested on Android 4.2.2 and 4.4.4)

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy() was called");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

When I press the back button, this method gets called (I saw the log).

I believe this should not happen unless phone gets low in memory or something. I have nothing much in the app but the MainActivity and some fragments.

Here is the log when the user is in the MainActivity and presses the back button:

```
I/MainActivity? onBackPressed() was called
I/MainActivity? onStop() was called
I/MainActivity? onDestroy() was called
```

Why this happens?

I also checked for `isFinishing()` in the `onPause()` and it always returns `true`

From the Javadoc :

> Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. **This can
>   happen** either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish
>   on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance
>   of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two
>   scenarios with the isFinishing method. Note: do not count on this
>   method being called as a place for saving data!

Comment: Nonono, you got the concept wrong. It's called when the `Activity` is destroyed, and in the simplest case, when you close it by pressing the back button. See [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for more information.

Comment: @AndrewT. Java doc says it can happen. it doesn't say it will happen. its confusing!

Comment: And funnily enough there are question in SO asking why onDestroy is not called on back pressed!

Comment: @Sean87 when the stack of fragments is 0 then backpress will call ondestroy to finish the activity

Comment: in the `onPause()` I also checked for `isFinishing()` and it always says TRUE

Comment: @Sean87 This is precisely the expected behavior. When you leave an activity via the back button, it is destroyed. Think it the other way: how could you possibly return to it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you press back button inside an `Activity`, it will call `finish()`, which will "close" it.

[**Activity.java**](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java)

```
/**
 * Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back
 * key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity,
 * but you can override this to do whatever you want.
 */
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mFragments.popBackStackImmediate()) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

When it happens, [`onDestroy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) can (and usually will) be called.

> protected void onDestroy ()
>
> Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (**someone called finish() on it**, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

The same reason also goes to why putting `isFinishing()` inside `onPause()` always returns `true`, **if you press the back button (call `finish()`)**. It will not return `true` if you hide the `Activity` with other method, e.g. pressing the home button.

Comment: I think it is really weird behavior of android. When the user simply switches activities it doesn't call onDestroy. I also have a serviceconnection that needs rewriting because of this - I want the service to keep on running when the user presses the back button. But I implemented - following google's guidelines - a service that isn't allowed to run when the application is killed. But now I have to change the service connection because the user doesn't want to kill the app when he / she uses the back button. 
I think google is quite inconsistent in it's choices. But thanks for pointing it out

Comment: It's also notable that when working with Fragment when you press the back button and observe the pattern lifecycle you'll notice that the `onStop()` state is first called before `onDestroy()`. Basically, if you want to handle your logic before the previous fragment comes to the foreground follow this callback trigger state pattern in this order State 1: `onPause`, State 2 `onStop()`, State 3`onDestroy` and then the previous fragment is called (`onCreate()`).